# Separar um paragrafo por frases

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso quebrar um paragrafo em um conjunto de frases.

Por exemplo:

```
var paragrafo = "Sou Dr. José. Meu passatempo é assistir séries. Adoro animais!! E você?";
var frases = paragrafo.split('.')
```

Porém ele acaba quebrando na palavra Dr. também:

```
var array = [
      "Sou Dr."
      " José."
      "Meu passatempo é assistir séries."
      "Adoro animais!! E você?"
    ];
```

O que espero que retorne é:

```
var array = [
  "Sou Dr. José."
  "Meu passatempo é assistir séries."
  "Adoro animais!!"
  "E você?"
];
```

Comment: Bem, você deve ter um critério definido para usar algum código para fazer isso. No seu exemplo com `split` estaria perfeito, mas o código não pode "saber" que o ponto depois de "Dr" não deve ser feito o `split`. Assim fica complicado, já que ponto apenas não resolve no seu caso.

Comment: para que você quer fazer isso? voce pode esta tendo a solução errada para um problema

Comment: Entendi, pesquisei um pouco e vi que posso fazer isso com regex, saberia uma forma aonde eu posso adicionar as excessões, com o cado de Dr.?

Comment: Em um contexto geral, preciso pegar paragrafos de um PDF (essa parte ja consegui), separar eles por frase e depois buscar em um banco de dados se existe um registro dessa frase lá.

Comment: Esse pode ser somente um exemplo e no caso real vc tera mais excessoes. Voce pode normalizar as excessoes antes de realizar o `split`. Como por exemplo antes de fazer `split` trocar *Dr.* por *Doutor* somente. Ira ter problemas com `...` em frases tambem, outra excessao. E assim por diante. Entao um passo antes do `split` eh criar um normalize com `replace`.

Comment: É, acho que posso usar isso, o problema é que vou ter MUITAS excessões pois os PDFs vão vir em diversas linguas... Mas acho que essa é a única saída.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solução (ECMAScript 2018 / ES9):**

```
.*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\b\w\w.)
```

**Demonstração:**

```js
var paragrafo = "Sou Dr. José. Meu passatempo é assistir séries. Adoro animais!! E você?";
var frases = paragrafo.match(/.*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\b\w\w\.)/g);
console.log(frases);
```

**Explicação:**

Antes de mais nada, já aviso que esse regex tem a limitação de deixar passar abreviações de apenas duas letras (e.g. "Dr.", "Sr.", "Pe.", "Mr." etc).

- `.*?[.!?]` - Aqui estamos capturando qualquer trecho de texto terminado com ponto final, exclamação ou interrogação. Utilizo um *lazy quantifier* para capturar cada parte separadamente.
- `(?![.!?])` - Esse é um *negative lookahead*. Aqui estamos dizendo para não aceitar um match se na frente dele houver uma dessas pontuações (usei para capturar também as pontuações repetidas, como no trecho `Adoro animais!!`).
- `(?<!\b\w\w.)` - Esse é um *negative lookbehind*. Aqui estamos dizendo para não capturar quando o nosso match terminar com um `\b` (representa um separador de palavras) e mais dois caracteres do tipo `\w` (que quer dizer o mesmo que  `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). Isso vai fazer com que textos como `Dr. José` ainda sejam considerados dentro da mesma frase, porém irá continuar separando se ocorrer algo como `Dra. Maria`.

Essa é a ideia dessa expressão regular. No entanto, se quisermos melhorar, como por exemplo remover os espaços que ficam sobrando no início das separações, podemos adicionar mais um *negative lookahead* para ignorar espaços:

```
(?! ).*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\b\w\w.)
```

E em vez de tentar generalizar todos os casos de abreviações, você pode querer inserir cada caso específico naquele *negative lookbehind* de antes:

```
(?! ).*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\bDr\.|Dra\.|Srs\.|Sras\.)
```

**Resultado final:**

```js
var paragrafo = "Sras. e Srs., eu sou Dr. José. Minha esposa é a Dra. Maria. Meu passatempo é assistir séries. Adoro animais!! E vocês?";
var frases = paragrafo.match(/(?! ).*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\bDr\.|Dra\.|Srs\.|Sras\.)/g);
console.log(frases);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

## Atualização:

A solução apresentada acima utiliza a nova funcionalidade de *lookbehind* implementada no ES9. Como o OP, em comentário abaixo, disse que está utilizando um navegador que ainda não suporta essa implementação, também apresento uma solução que não usa *lookbehind*:

```
(?! )(.*?(\b\w\w\.))*.*?[.?!](?![.?!])
```

**Explicação:**

- `(?! )` - É um *lookahead* que eu utilizado para não capturar os espaços que sobram atrás das frases.
- `(.*?(\b\w\w\.))*` - Aqui eu capturo qualquer caractere até chegar às exceções. Defini como regra geral o mesmo padrão explicado antes (`\b\w\w\.`), mas você também tem a opção de adicionar as exceções separadamente como no exemplo com o *lookbehind*. Esse padrão é colocado em um grupo de captura, e eu coloco um quantificador `*` após ele, para dizer que ele pode se repetir zero ou mais vezes.
- `.*?[.?!]` - Aqui são capturados todos os caracteres, utilizando um *lazy quantifier*, até chegar ao ponto final, exclamação ou interrogação mais próximos.
- `(?![.?!])` - Esse é um *negative lookahead*. Quer dizer que eu não quero nenhum match seguido de uma pontuação. Uso para capturar frases como `Adoro animais!!`.

**Demonstração:**

```js
var paragrafo = "Sou Dr. José. Meu passatempo é assistir séries. Adoro animais!! E você?";
var frases = paragrafo.match(/(?! )(.*?(\b\w\w\.))*.*?[.?!](?![.?!])/g);
console.log(frases);
```

Comment: mas em javascript não existe negative lookbehind ;/

Comment: @Paz O lookbehind em expressões regulares no Javascript está no estágio 4 do TC39, o que quer dizer que [essa funcionalidade já foi implementada no ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind). Inclusive, já está disponível a partir da versão 62 do Chrome.

Comment: Que ótimo, não fazia idéia... +1

Comment: Parece uma ótima solução! Mas quando eu passo pro browser ele me retorna SyntaxError: invalid regexp group. Estou usando o Firefox

Comment: @Juliano Infelizmente o Firefox ainda não suporta a implementação do lookbehind do Javascript, pois essa é uma funcionalidade recente. Essa expressão regular só vai funcionar para o Google Chrome a partir da versão 62.

Comment: Existe uma forma de escapar os números também? Exemplo: 190.923.

Tentei dessa forma: (?! ).*?[.!?](?![.!?])(?<!\bDr\.|Dra\.|Srs\.|Sras\.|[0-9]\.[0-9]\.)

Mas não funcionou

Comment: Funciona se você usar apenas `\d\.` em vez de `[0-9]\.[0-9]\.`.